# how to parse html with nutch and index specific tag to solr?

Tags: solr, nutch, apache-tika

i have installed nutch and solr for crawling a website and search in it; as you know we can index meta tags of webpages into solr with parse meta tags plugin of nutch.(http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IndexMetatags) now i want to know is there any way to crawl another html tag to solr that isn't meta?(plugin or anyway) like this:

```
<div id=something>
      me specific tag
</div>
```

indeed i want to add a field to solr (something) that have value of "me specific tag" in this page.

any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I made my own plugin for something similar you want to.
The config file for mapping NutchDocument to SolrDocument is in $NUTCH_HOME/conf/**solrindex-mapping.xml**. Here you can add your own tags. But still you have to fill your own tags somewhere.

Here are some tips to plugin:

- read http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample, here you can find how to make your plugin very simply
- in your plugin extend the **ParseFilter** and **IndexingFilter.**
- in *YourParseFilter* you can use **NodeWalker** to find your specific div
- your parsed informations put into page metadata like this

  `page.putToMetadata(new Utf8("yourKEY"), ByteBuffer.wrap(YourByteArrayParsedFromMetaData));`
- in *YourIndexingFilter* add the metadata from page (page.getMetadata) to NutchDocument

  `doc.add("your_specific_tag", value);`
- **most important!!!!!**
- put **your_specific_tag** to fileds of:

  - **Solr** config file **schema.xml** (and restart Solr)

  field name="your_specific_tag" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"

  - **Nutch** config file **schema.xml** (don't know if it is realy neccessary)
  - **Nutch** config file **solrindex-mapping.xml**

  field dest="your_specific_tag" source="your_specific_tag"

Comment: I've done this also, but somehow, some metadata gets lost in the proccess. I look for it in the IndexingFilter, getMetadata().get("my_tag") returns null

Answer (score 2):

u have to just try http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.in/2013/08/nutch2-crawl-and-index-extra-tag.html 
the tutorial said img tag how to get and what all are steps are there mention...

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these custom plugins to parse xml files based on xpath (or css selectors):

- https://github.com/BayanGroup/nutch-custom-search
- http://www.atlantbh.com/precise-data-extraction-with-apache-nutch/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [Nutch Plugin](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-978) which should allow you to extract an element from a web page.