# Using Solr for indexing HTML tags with attributes

Tags: solr, nutch

I have crawled websites using Nutch and I have pushed crawled data to solr. Now I want to search content between specific tag with specific attribute value. For example,

```
 <h><title> title to search </title></h>
 <div id="abc">
     content to search
 </div>
 <div class="efg">
     other content to search
 </div>
```

I have seen this question([how to parse html with nutch and index specific tag to solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338967/how-to-parse-html-with-nutch-and-index-specific-tag-to-solr)) but this does not have enough clarity.

I want to know that whether there is any plugin available or i need to write a customized plugin altogether. If i have to write a plugin, i just need few directions for handling html tags and attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `HTMLStripCharFilterFactory` in your analyzer before tokenizing.

This filter `strips HTML from the input stream`. For more info have a look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory)

Comment: Thanks for your response !! Is it possible to index on the basis of value of attributes(i.e. id or class,etc) of a HTML tags. In the above example, abc for id and efg for class.

Comment: I don't think so. You will have to fetch these values on your own and index them, maybe in some other field. The `HTMLStripCharFilterFactory` does not help you in this.

Comment: Ok. Let's say I know the values of attributes like title, description, details, etc. Should/Can I add these attributes values inside schema.xml for solr in addition to HTMLStripCharFilterFactory analyzer?

Comment: Well I process the data that I have and then add it. You need to design your schema according to your requirements.

Comment: Is it possible that you can describe a little bit more, it seems that you have a good knowledge Solr? can you come for a brief chat on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a Nutch filter (I like [Jericho HTML Parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html)) to extract only the parts of the page you need to index using DOM manipulation. You can use the [TextExtractor](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/TextExtractor.html) class to grab clean text (sans HTML tags) to be used in your index. I usually save that data in custom fields.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir!! I have one more question..what do you mean by saving the data in custom fields?

Comment: Custom fields in the Solr index.