# How to make nutch index only pages with certain text?

Tags: nutch

I have 2 requirements.

First one is that I want Nutch to index only pages that contain certain words in the html. For example I only want nutch to index pages that contain "wounderful" word in the html.
Second one is that I want nutch to index certain URLs from the site. For example I want nutch to index URLs that are similar to "mywebsite.com/XXXX/ABC/XXXX" or "mywebsite.com/grow.php/ABC/XXXX", where "XXXX" can be any word of any length.

This is the content of my seed.txt file

```
http://mysite.org/
```

this is the content of my regex-urlfilter.txt

```
+^http://mysite.org/work/.*?/text/
```

I have commented

```
#+.
```

By I am still getting below error

```
crawl started in: crawl
rootUrlDir = bin/urls
threads = 10
depth = 3
solrUrl=http://localhost:8983/solr/
topN = 5
Injector: starting at 2013-07-09 11:05:51
Injector: crawlDb: crawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: bin/urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: total number of urls rejected by filters: 1
Injector: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 0
Injector: Merging injected urls into crawl db.
Injector: finished at 2013-07-09 11:06:08, elapsed: 00:00:17
Generator: starting at 2013-07-09 11:06:08
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
Generator: filtering: true
Generator: normalizing: true
Generator: topN: 5
Generator: jobtracker is 'local', generating exactly one partition.
Generator: 0 records selected for fetching, exiting ...
Stopping at depth=0 - no more URLs to fetch.
No URLs to fetch - check your seed list and URL filters.
crawl finished: crawl
```

Comment: Nutch doesn't index anything, it only parses content.

Comment: Okay may be I should restate my question.How can I tell Nutch to ignore these pages? If solr does the indexing than is there a way to do what I have asked in my main question via Solr?

Answer (score 2):

[Start here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884249/nutch-regex-urlfilter-syntax) to setup your desired URL pattern. Then [look into plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341072/using-solr-for-indexing-html-tags-with-attributes) to parse your content and decide what should be indexed.

Comment: I have tried setting up the filter just like told in other ticket like http://mysite.com/work/(.+)*$ but it says Injector: total number of urls rejected by filters: 1 and 0 injected

Comment: I got it right by adding this URL in seed.txt http://mysite.com/work/ and this +^http://mysite.com/work/([a-z0-9]*\.)* in regex-urlfilter.txt. Not sure if this is the right way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

It shows Injector rejects your url in seed file

```
Injector: total number of urls rejected by filters: 1
```

Your regex is not working or there will be any other patterns which rejects your url like `-.*(/[^/]+)/[^/]+\1/[^/]+\1/` or `-[?*!@=]`

Answer (score 0):

Know this is pretty old, but just wanted to add my two cents to the topic related the crawling vs. indexing filter, for nutch-1.13

---

**regex-urlfilter testing**

If you want to test your regex-urlfilter.txt expressions you can use the plugin testing like this

```
$ bin/nutch plugin urlfilter-regex org.apache.nutch.urlfilter.regex.RegexURLFilter
```

This will give no feedback, but if you type urls and press enter, you'll see an echo of it, with a '-' or '+' prefix, telling you if the url passes the configuration filter.

such as

```
http://aaa.com
-http://aaa.com
http://bbb.com
+http://bbb.com
```

if config is something like

```
+^http://bbb.com\.*
-.*
```

**crawling filter vs. index filter**

This is not well documented, and took me a while to found a clue.
If we want to make different filtering precision (broad on crawling, but more detailed on indexing) we can do the following.

First, if we're using the bin/crawl script, just add

- a -filter option at the end of the filtering command
- the param that specifies the regex file to use; -Durlfilter.regex.file)

like this

```
<  __bin_nutch index $JAVA_PROPERTIES "$CRAWL_PATH"/crawldb -linkdb "$CRAWL_PATH"/linkdb "$CRAWL_PATH"/segments/$SEGMENT
>  __bin_nutch index $JAVA_PROPERTIES -Durlfilter.regex.file=regex-urlfilter-index.txt "$CRAWL_PATH"/crawldb -linkdb "$CRAWL_PATH"/linkdb "$CRAWL_PATH"/segments/$SEGMENT -filter
```

Otherwise, just append both parameters to the bin/nutch index command, if you're using them without the crawl script

And now, enter the desired configuration in the 'regex-urlfilter-index.txt' file.

Thanks to Arthurs question in grokbase for the insight:
http://grokbase.com/t/nutch/user/1579evs40h/filtering-at-index-time-with-a-different-regex-urlfilter-txt-from-crawl