# Nutch skip url containing #

Tags: regex, nutch

I am learning Nutch. I have set up nutch and started crawling sites. But one thing I am unable to figure out is how to restrict url containing # as several duplication is going on due to this #. 
I have checked the regex-urlfilter.txt

```
# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
-[*!@]
```

If I add # to this line conceptually this should work but after adding # It's not working. Is it due to # used to comment lines? If so how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `#` using a backslash?

Comment: I was just gonna say that. Added backslash and bingo. How silly.
Thanks for your response. :)

Comment: Nice one @JayChakra. I've formalised the answer if you're happy to accept.

Comment: @RobertBain: Sure why not

Comment: @RobertBain: Is there some way in nutch to parse the HTML distinctively like say body to index in body field of solr, title in title field of solr and so on.

Any lead is highly appriciated

Comment: I'm afraid I came to this question through the regex topic, rather than nutch. It's definitely worth asking a new question.

Comment: @RobertBain: Thanks, I have found solution on SO here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338967/how-to-parse-html-with-nutch-and-index-specific-tag-to-solr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the `#` using a backslash.